# Appending charaters in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am trying to append characters in a string but I am getting problem with the loop. I don't know the command to append characters in the string:

```
import string
import random

def main():
  generateRandomNumbers()
def generateRandomNumbers():
    nameLength = 10
    for i in range(nameLength)
       x = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase )
       uname.append(x)
    print (x)
size = 0
nameLength=0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting following error message:

```
File "Fl.py", line 8
    for i in range(nameLength)
                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: just `+` for append to a str

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python append character to string", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: I did lot of search, I can't find a single program to store characters in an empty string.

Comment: you mean: uname += x

Comment: What about the loop problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the syntax error because you are missing a colon at the end of your for loop. It should look like this:

```
for i in range(nameLength):
```

As Kenan has already said, I would recommend using the `+` operator to append to a string. This [article](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) has some decent examples that should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks but please write colon instead of semicolon.

Comment: Sorry your answer is not working. I am getting several errors. Why are you not showing a complete program. Errors are: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Fl.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  Fl.py", line 5, in main
    generateRandomNumbers()
  Fl.py", line 10, in generateRandomNumbers
    uname + x
NameError: name 'uname' is not defined

Comment: Adding the colon should resolve the original syntax error you were having. As far as the NameError, that is because you never defined the variable 'uname'. In line 10, you try to append 'x' to it, but 'uname' has no value. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish with this method, but if you want 'uname' to have a specific value when you add 'x' to it, then define it as uname = 'uname value goes here' before attempting to append 'x' to it.